# Order of every element of group <{I, R, R', R''}, *> of rotations of a rhombus

Tags: rotations, symmetry

For the case of the group <{I, R, R', R''}, *> of rotations of a square, I said:

|I| = 1

|R| = 4

|R'| = 2

|R''| = 4

For a rhombus, do I need to take into consideration the symmetry of it to obtain the order of its rotations? or can I say its rotations have the same order as in a square given that they have the same number of elements?

Comment: What do you mean by diamond? The octahedron?

Comment: A diamond has fewer rotations than a square.

Comment: @3311411 Sorry, a rhombus. I didn't know the term in english and google translate said it was called a diamond

Comment: I don't think that thinking about a square is a helpful approach.  You are better off just considering the symmetries of a rhombus separately.  There are 4 vertices.  Which ones can map to which via a rotation?  This should help you write down the rotations of a rhombus.

Comment: @tkf thanks! I will take that approach